# git setup for local development

Tags: git, repository

I had went through few Git Tutorial and Essential Training, I had basic knowledge for GIT.
What I had learn from the tutorial, they teach me how to init git repository / github (as remote).

I got a question. Since GIT is Distribution repository. As I do some researches. I found that a lot of people are creating local / server repository and ask their colleague or developer check out in machine.

Is GIT possible do it without a so call "server repository". Developer B can clone the repository from Developer A. Developer B can push his code to Developer A. 
What I means there is no one "server / central" Github / repository. A and B their can do their push / pull update between them.
Lets say suddenly Developer C come into the team, he can either get the source code from A / B master branch.

Is this concept correct? If yes, is there any tutorial / book teach how this able to setup?

I hope I make my question clear. If you need any clarify please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have shell access to the other machine you can simply do

```
git clone <user>@<machine>:~/somerepository
```

to clone the repo. To pull you do

```
git pull <user>@<machine>:~/somerepository
```

That's it. If you don't have shell access you can also pull via http if the files if the files are distributed via web server.

Comment: I am in windows environment. Let's say I need to clone from Machine A, pc name is pc1, username is john. the repository sit on c:\www\test. What is the command?

Comment: I don't use Windows. But I hardly believe that the git syntax changes on Windows. You can try using `ssh://<user>@<machine>:22:~/somerepo`. Do you have shell access?

Answer (score 1):

Thank Macro for the answer,

I got my full answer from this link.

http://www.gosammy.com/2011/06/14/using-git-between-mac-and-windows/

Thanks!